# Is it possible to use iNotes with document mode 8 in an iFrame / Frame?

Tags: email, iframe, frame, document, lotus

So here is my problem:
I have a website coded in xPages that loads iNotes (E-Mail Client) in an iFrame. Problem is that iNotes only works with document mode set to IE8 but I do not want to put the entire page into that document mode. So as it isn’t possible to set different document modes for iframes (at least I read that at microsoft and it didn’t work when I tried it) I thought about using frames where it seems to be (again: read it) possible.

So the question is, will it work? Before spending a lot of hours into a solution that does not, I wanted to ask here. Especially because someone might come up with an even better solution (which would be greatly appreciated!) ...